# MySQL Inner Join too slow

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-5.7, query-performance

My machine disk is SSD and memory is 32GB.
My executed SQL:

```sql
SELECT `country_detail`.`country_name` AS `country_name`
FROM `statistic_detail`
  INNER JOIN `country_detail` ON (`statistic_detail`.`country` = `country_detail`.`country_code`)
GROUP BY 1;
```

The SQL need cost 30 second. So slowly! My explain is:
[image]
I don't understand why it need so much time?
I know how optimize it, I want to know why it is so slow.

My table information is:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `statistic_detail` (
  `date` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `os` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `ver` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `utype` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `stype` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `language` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `num0` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `num1` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `num2` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `num3` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `num4` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `num5` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `num6` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `num7` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `num8` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `num9` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `num10` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `num11` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `num12` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `num13` double NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`country`, `ver`, `language`, `utype`, `stype`, `os`, `date`),  
  KEY `ver_idx` (`ver`),
  KEY `language_idx` (`language`),
  KEY `utype_idx` (`utype`),
  KEY `stype_idx` (`stype`),
  KEY `os_idx` (`os`),
  KEY `date_idx` (`date`),
  KEY `country_idx` (`country`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

13731253 rows.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `country_detail` (
  `country_code` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `country_name` varchar(16),
  `region_code` varchar(16),
  `region_name` varchar(16),
  PRIMARY KEY (`country_code`),
  KEY `region_code_idx` (`region_code`),
  KEY `region_name_idx` (`region_name`),
  KEY `country_name_idx` (`country_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

334 rows.

Comment: Suggest making types consistent.  Note that the country_code is 16 vs 20 characters.  Also, `CHAR(2) CHARSET ascii` makes more sense for that column (if you are using the 2-letter standard).

Comment: Side note, ISO 3166 (country_code) is either 2 or 3 characters, why are you using 16/20? It also strikes me as rather odd that the code is longer than the name. There are plenty of countries with official names longer than 16, example: "The Federal Democratic Republic of Ethiopia" which is 43 characters long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand the reason behind slowness of your current query, you need to understand the [Nested Loop Join algorithm](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/nested-loop-joins.html) used by MySQL. Basically, for every `country_code` value in the country table, it is looking for **all** the matching rows in the statistic table. So if you look at your explain, it is roughly accessing 334*306 rows (a large number). Unfortunately, in this case, MySQL optimizer is not smart enough to stop searching for the row as soon as a match is found (because you are using `Group By`, and no aggregation function is being used).

Now, `JOIN` is unnecessary here, as it seems that you are just looking to check that the "country" has atleast one corresponding row in the `statistic_detail` table. This query can be written in a more *performant* way using [`EXISTS()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) on a [Correlated Subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/correlated-subqueries.html). `Exists()` stops as soon as a matching row is found in the statistic table.

Try the following query:

```
SELECT cd.country_name
FROM country_detail AS cd 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM statistic_detail AS sd 
              WHERE sd.country = cd.country_code)
```

If `country_name` values are not UNIQUE in the `country_detail` table, you can additionally utilize `DISTINCT` clause to get rid of duplicates:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cd.country_name
FROM country_detail AS cd 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM statistic_detail AS sd 
              WHERE sd.country = cd.country_code)
```

Comment: @study_20160808 It is not about 100K rows being large; it is about how many actual disk I/O operations you are doing to get the result of a query. If you do 100k disk I/O operations in a query in any RDBMS, it would be slow. That is why queries should be written to minimze disk I/O

Comment: @study_20160808 you can have milions (even bilions) of rows in your tables in MySQL easily. But you dont need to be accessing all of them in a single query.

Comment: @RaymondNijland MySQL almost always uses NLJ. I am not suggesting that it is using BNL (Block Nested Loop) here. Even if it is Nested Loop, my understanding here is that in the first table (country table), it is having 334 rows to loop over, and in the second level (of the nested loop), it is accessing (on an average) 306 rows **per loop**. That's why I said **334*306** lookups happening.

Comment: agreed, i readed the question way to literal removed that comment..  Annyhow the MySQL `EXPLAIN` gives to little infromation a `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON` gives more as i have a feeling that materialization is the topicstarters issue here .. But you are right a ref type indeed indicates a random (memory/disk) i/o lookup per joined record...

Comment: Just found out today that that [old join processing](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/nested-loop-joins.html#block-nested-loop-join-algorithm) which you mentioned in this question and comments might be running more optimized soon when MySQL 8.0.18 is released as [hash join optimisation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/hash-joins.html) comes to MySQL...

Comment: @RaymondNijland thanks for the interesting and encouraging info. Although, I believe our first target should be to have appropriate indexes for fast lookups; because Hash Join will come into picture only if there are no appropriate indexes and atleast one equality condition in the join

Comment: *"Hash Join will come into picture only if there are no appropriate indexes and atleast one equality condition in the join"* yes agreed about the indexing..  i assume this is the first step into fully supporting hash joins..